# Does jshell work with jmod files?

Tags: jshell, jmod

I followed some example and I created a simple jmod.
I put jmod in my jmod folder not in java jmods folder.
Now, I read that jshell can export modules, but I did understand.
Can jshell work with jmods? 
Some example?
In java jmods folder there are many jmod files, but I don't know how to use it in jshell session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jmod file contains all (binary) artifacts of a java module - java .class files, native libraries (.so/.dll), executables, config files etc. jmod files are not meant to be used at runtime with launcher tools such as java, jshell, jjs. jmod files are used with jlink tool to create a runtime image.